# Visual Studio cannot find GetLocale() function used in VBScript as part of XSL

Tags: xml, visual-studio-2012, vbscript, xslt-1.0, msxsl

I am trying to debug XSLT in Visual Studio 2012 and I am getting following error:

error: 'GetLocale' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

I am implementing script

```
<msxsl:script language="VBScript" implements-prefix="testCmnVBS">
  ...
Dim localeID
localeID = GetLocale ()

  ...
</msxsl>
```

So this should be the way to use it according to [MSFT Sample](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/232158/EN-US)

But it seems like it is not seeing it. Anyone have idea why?

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you've used **GetLocale ()** and not **GetLocale()** which is preventing it from being seen.